# Why the output is not in numerical form in Mathematica 12.2?

Tags: regions, numerical-value, computational-geometry, version-12.2

Consider the following code:

```
ROffAxisArb[θ_, ztodet_] = ztodet*Tan[θ];
circle[ztodet_, θ_] := 
  Circle[{0, 0}, ROffAxisArb[θ, ztodet]];
rectangle[xtodet_, ytodet_, dxdet_, dydet_] := 
  Rectangle[{xtodet - dxdet/2, ytodet - dydet/2}, {xtodet + dxdet/2, 
    ytodet + dydet/2}];
xtodetValue = 0.;
ytodetValue = 0.;
dxdetValue = 5.;
dydetValue = 5.;
ztodetValue = 8.7 + 3.;
intersection = 
 RegionIntersection[
  rectangle[xtodetValue, ytodetValue, dxdetValue, dydetValue], 
  circle[ztodetValue, 0.25]]
ArcLength[
 RegionIntersection[
  rectangle[xtodetValue, ytodetValue, dxdetValue, dydetValue], 
  circle[ztodetValue, 0.25]]]
```

I would expect that if a least one number entering the evaluation is with `.` in the end, ArcLength should return a numeric value. In Mathematica 11.1 it really gives so. In contrast, in Mathematica 12.2 it gives

```
(1178357340 (ArcSin[98607293/117835734] - 
   ArcSin[Sqrt[4161861974530907]/117835734]))/98607293
```

Could you please tell me whether it is possible to get the numerical value apart from entering all the numbers with `.`?

Comment: The default `WorkingPrecision` for `ArcLength` must have changed. Use `ArcLength[RegionIntersection[rectangle[xtodetValue, ytodetValue, dxdetValue, dydetValue], circle[ztodetValue, 0.25]], WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]`

Comment: Try to add `...//N` after your code.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch : yes, but is it possible to solve this issue without adding?

Comment: It seems that `RegionIntersection` will always return a result with rational numbers.  Bob's solution with `WorkingPrecision` is faster than applying `N` afterwards.  You could evaluate `SetOptions[ArcLength, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]`